# Application Development architectures

Tags: java, architecture

I would like to know various application development archtecture available for free/commercial . I know Appfuse and Spring Roo . Do we have any other best choices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Java RAD web framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360963/best-java-rad-web-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360963/best-java-rad-web-framework).